# Discrete Topology vs Euclidean Topology

Tags: general-topology

It's a very short question but I'd like to confirm my udnerstanding on the difference b/w discrete and Euclidean topologies in $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm understanding it that Euclidean topology is a discrete topology except singletons since we can't have the positive distance in there. Is it correct?

** I've gone through [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764572/is-the-euclidean-usual-standard-topology-on-mathbbrn-kind-of-like-the-disc) but still the difference was a bit unclear so I've created my own post.

Comment: They are not even close. How do you define a topology, in general?

Comment: No.  In a discrete space EVERY subset is open.  That's not true (at all) in the Euclidean topology.

Comment: Both discrete spaces and the Euclidean line have the property that one-point sets are closed.  That's about where the similarities end.

Comment: @Randall, hmm we have open balls in Euclidean topology, right? so aren't they open?

Comment: Sure they are.  Is every subset you could possibly conceive open?   No.

Comment: @Randall, sorry, could you give me some example??

Comment: oh, you mean, for instance, something like [a, b] where a and b are reals?

Comment: Right.  Or something like $\{a\}$, which is open in the discrete topology but not in the Euclidean.  Or the $x$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$, or the set of rationals in $\mathbb{R}$, or.....

Comment: Got it!! Thank you so much for your follow-up! That makes sense!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discrete topology over a set $X$ is the topology where every subset of $X$ is open. The Euclidean topology (over a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$)is the topology generated by the "balls", i.e. $B(x,r):=\{ y \in X \ : \ || y-x || < r\} \ $, where "generated" means that each open can be written as arbitrary (as many as you want) union of balls.

A lot of subsets are not open in the euclidean topology, such as points (singletons), closed intervals/iperintervals ( $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ or $[a_{1},b_{1}] \times ... \times [a_{n}, b_{n}]$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ).